# DataGridViewCell trap CTRL+Up or CTRL+Down

Tags: c#, event-handling, datagridviewtextboxcell, editmode

C# form has a `datagridview`. I need to trap an event when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> Arrow or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> Arrow is pressed in a **cell** in edit mode.

Not sure which event to handle and how it should be handled.

Comment: use DataGridView KeyPress event. Get the edited cell from DataGridView.CurrentCell.

Comment: To test the key up in KeyPress event : if (((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control) && e.KeyChar == Keys.Up) ...

Comment: You got it Graffito.  Thanks.  I'd give you a +1, but don't yet have enough reputation to give to do so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the `KeyUp` event for your `DataGridView` like this :

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Ctrl+{0}",e.KeyCode.ToString()));
    else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Ctrl+{0}", e.KeyCode.ToString()));
}
```

Adding the print screen i get when i actually run the code:

[image]

From MSDN:

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool
>   operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

> The & operator can function as either a unary or a binary operator.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Because both operands are `bool` in my code, `&&` is the preferred option, although i tested with `&` and it worked as well. Also `&&` is more efficient because it tests the second operand only if necessary.

Comment: i added a print screen from my test for the code i posted showing the message box when CTRL+UP is pressed.

Comment: @Rob did you actually test the code? I repeated my test and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Rob i also added explanation for the choice of && operator over & operator.

Comment: mea culpa. I confused your answer with graffito's.     I've removed my comment and will give you the check off.